# How do I call a client side function from the server using meteor?

Tags: meteor

Ok so I'm currently doing this and it works, but it seems a bit hacky.  Is there a better way to call a function on the client side after a certain amount of time on the server side passes? On the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('notifications');

Notifications.find().observe({ //Call whatever function. 
    added: function(item){ 
        console.log(item);
        alert(item.text)
    }
});
```

And this on the server.

```
Meteor.publish('notifications', function(){
    return Notifications.find({createdBy:this.userId});
});

//These run after a certain interval of time passes:  
Notifications.insert({text: text, createdBy:createdBy});
Notifications.remove({text: text, createdBy:createdBy});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a collection on the server side for sending notifications to the client

Comment: What do you mean?  I have a collection that I'm using to send push notifications, but I'm also trying to include desktop notifications

Comment: Collections allow you to push updates to the client.  So if you want to send a client a message, you can.    I'm not quite sure why your are saying you are sending push notifcations, but trying to do desktop notifications?  Not sure what you mean by desktop

Comment: I'm sorry my question was a bit confusing, but I wasn't quite sure how to phrase it.  I made edits above to more clearly ask my question.  Thank you very much.